# Swift2 open segue from non main thread

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to open segue from non main thread.

I am calling a static method from a class from the active view, which looks like this:

```
import Foundation

class Request
{
    static func callRequest(headers: [String: String]?, url: String, method: String, params: [String]?, view: UIViewController?, completion: AnyObject? -> ())
    {
        if notOnline() {
//            view!.performSegueWithIdentifier("internetErrorSegue", sender: view)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                view!.performSegueWithIdentifier("internetErrorSegue", sender: view!)
            }
        }
   }
}
```

And from my ViewController, I am calling callRequest method like this:

```
        Request.callRequest(
            nil,
            url: someUrl,
            method: "POST",
            params: sendingData,
            view: self) { json in
                // processing json response
                print(json)
            }) 
}
```

What should happen is that if I don't have internet, it should open a segue `internetErrorSegue`. But what happens is that it actually goes through line where `performSegueWithIdentfier` is called and nothing happens - it stays stuck in the application (like when I press the button).

There is a existing segue between 2 two view controllers that I am using.

Comment: If your code is running through the segue, I'd check the segue itself to make sure it's connected properly. Can you call that segue from the VC itself?

Comment: Check storyboard connections and try to clean the project.

Comment: why can't your call your segue after your completion handler inside your view controller. Bet that resolves everything. Also, make sure your view controller is fully loaded before calling your performSegue. If you're making your Request the moment your view controller is created you'll never be able to segue.

Comment: I called segue in completion handler and it worked as expected. Thanks!